# Selecting an image from an NSArray in a for loop

Tags: objective-c, arrays, macos, nsimage

So I've got these number codes which correspond to an item, and I need to get an image for each item to display in a table. (All the table etc is sorted, just this image selection..)

I've got this so far, which only returns the blockNotFound.png. I need it to return the corresponding 'block-X.png' for each 'itemId' requested.

```
+ (NSImage *)imageForItemId:(uint16_t)itemId {
    NSSize          itemImageSize = NSMakeSize(32, 32);
    NSImage         *output = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:itemImageSize];
    NSString        *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSFileManager   *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray         *imageArray = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];

    for (id object in imageArray) {
        NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/block-%d.png",path,itemId];
        // This NSLog does list all files in imagePath.
        // NSLog(imagePath);
        if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]) {
            output = [NSImage imageNamed:imagePath];
        } else {
            output = [NSImage imageNamed:@"blockNotFound.png"];
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That `for` loop makes no sense. You are not using `object` inside the loop so you might as well not have a loop at all.

Comment: What would I replace `object` with then?

Comment: The first thing you have to do is understand your code. Why did you write the loop in the first place? What is it supposed to do? Why do you think you need it?

Comment: It's supposed to go through all the files (images) in `path`, then filters `itemId` through them, if `output` exists, set it, if not, set it to blockNotFound.png.

Comment: So do you realize that the loop is not helping here? You are just executing the same block of code multiple times, always with the same result. The loop is simply not needed because `[fm fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]` already loops through all files you are interested in. You don't need `imageArray` either. And while we're at it, it is wrong to first create an `NSImage` (line 3) and then assign a different object to the variable.

Comment: Hm. I see... I don't understand what you mean by the NSImage NSSize variable. It's `initWithSize`'ing just like what Apples' docs say. `- (id)initWithSize:(NSSize)aSize`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this "sounds" more applicable.

```
+ (NSImage *)imageForItemId:(NSUInteger)itemId {

    NSSize          itemImageSize = NSMakeSize(32, 32); // use it to set the size later
    NSImage         *output;
    NSFileManager   *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];



    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *imagePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"block-%d.png",itemId]];

    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]) {
        output = [NSImage imageNamed:imagePath];
    } 
    else {
        output = [NSImage imageNamed:@"blockNotFound.png"];
    }


    return output;
}
```

Comment: No reason for a for-loop, maybe this is why you don't use the `object` anywhere in its block ;)

Comment: That still sets all images to blockNotFound.png. :3

Comment: Obviously there are no images matching the imagePath.